Не работает 2D свет в Unity URP
Я создал и сбилдил 2D игру в unity, использовал 2D свет через URP. Но в билде на каких то устройствах свет есть, а на других его нет. В чём может быть проблема?

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.
